# Is it possible to make simple postgres dump using replication server?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, barman

PostgreSQL 9.6, configured backup server via `barman` tool. Using WAL streaming (pg_receivexlog) and streaming backup (pg_basebackup).

All working good. However for development/debugging purposes I may need to create simple dump and copy it to localhost to inspect.

On master server I can simply use `pg_dump` tool. But I don't want to use it under heavy production load. So I was thinking - is there a way to create dump from our backup server?

Only one way I can think about: apply `barman recover` command to different server (not production), then there create simple dump via `pg_dump`. That will work, but isn't there a way to ditch intermediate server?

Comment: You can use `pg_dump` on the standby provided it is configured as a "hot standby"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can only run `pg_dump` against a running PostgreSQL server.

You can avoid the necessity to recover the database whenever you need a `pg_dump` by setting up a streaming replication hot standby server with `max_standby_streaming_delay = -1` and run your `pg_dump` against that.